# Minimum Window Substring

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures

I'm working on the Leetcode "[Minimum Window Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/)" practice problem:

> Given two strings `s` and `t` of lengths `m` and `n` respectively, return the ***minimum window substring*** of `s` such that every character in `t` (*including duplicates*) is included in the window. If there is no such substring, return the empty string "".
>
> The testcases will be generated such that the answer is unique.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: s = "ADOBECODEBANC", t = "ABC"
> Output: "BANC"
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: s = "a", t = "a"
> Output: "a"
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: s = "a", t = "aa"
> Output: ""
> Explanation: Both `'a'`s from `t` must be included in the window. Since the largest window of `s` only has one `'a'`, return empty string.

My solution uses two maps to keep track of character counts:

- `strr` map is to keep count of characters in the window and
- `patt` map is for the given pattern string.

It also uses two indices, `start` and `end`, to keep track of the current window (which includes `end`).

The core of the solution is an outer loop that advances `end`, adding the new character to `strr`. It then runs an inner loop as long as the window is valid that:

- checks & updates the shortest window seen so far
- removes the first character in the window
- advances `start`.

Once the outer loop finishes, the shortest window it encountered should be the answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

bool check_map(std::unordered_map<char, int> patt, std::unordered_map<char, int> strr)
{
  for(auto data:patt)
  {
    if(strr[data.first] != data.second)
      return false; 
  }
  return true;
}

std::string Substring(std::string s, std::string t)
{
  std::unordered_map<char, int> patt;
  std::unordered_map<char, int> strr;
  std::string ans;
  for(int i=0; i<t.length(); i++)
    patt[t[i]]++;
  int start = 0, length = INT_MAX;;
  for(int end=0; end<s.length(); end++)
  {
    strr[s[end]]++;
    while(check_map(patt, strr))
    {
      if(length > (end-start+1))
      {
        ans = s.substr(start, end+1);
        length = end-start+1;
      }
      strr[s[start]]--;
      if(strr[s[start]] == 0)
        strr.erase(s[start]);
      
      start++;
    }
  }
  return ans;
}

int main()
{
  std::string s = "ADOBECODEBANC",
    pattern = "ABC";
  std::cout << "String: " << s << std::endl
            << "Pattern: " << pattern << std::endl
            << "Minimum Window Substring is " << Substring(s, pattern) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For example 1 from the problem, the program should return "BANC" but instead returns "ADOBEC". Program output:

> ```
> String: ADOBECODEBANC
> Pattern: ABC
> Minimum Window Substring is ADOBEC
> ```

Where is the error in my code?

Comment: *"Can you please help me with the error in the code"* What error??

Comment: Related: [What do you mean, "it doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: Can you explain what your code is supposed to be doing?  Why are you using two maps?  What is the purpose of each?  Why are you erasing from the string?     It is very difficult to find problems with your code when it has no explanation.

Comment: [Homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527)?

Comment: I practice coding porblems and that's how it got stuck on it. Nope, not a homework @outis

Comment: Currently, the question should be clear and ambiguous. However, it still likely should be closed with reason "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo. (While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.)"

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry that I cannot answer your concrete question to “where is the error in my code”.

But what I can do, is to help you to understand the problem, develop an algorithm and show, one of many, potential solution.

The title of the question already implies, what algorithm shall be used: The so called “Sliding Window”-algorithm.

You will find a very good explanation from  Said Sryheni  [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/sliding-window-algorithm).

And for your problem, we will use the Flexible-Size Sliding window approach.

We will iterate over the source string character by character and wait, until we meet a certain condition. In this case, until we “saw” all characters that needs to be searched for. Then, we will find a window, in which all these characters are.

In the given example, the end of the sliding window is always the last read character from the source string. This, because the last read character fulfills the condition. Then we need to find the beginning of the window. In that case the position of the rightmost character (of the search characters) in the source string that still fulfills the condition.

Then we will continue to read the source string and wait for the next condition to be fulfilled. And then we will recalculate the sliding window positions.

By the way. The other characters, besides the search characters in the source string, are just noise and will only extend the width of the sliding window.

But how do we meet the condition?

And especially, since the order of the search characters does not matter, and, there can even be double characters in it?

The solution is that we will “count”.

First, we will count the occurrence of all characters in the search string. Additionally, we will use a second counter that indicates if all characters are matched.

Then, while iterating over the source string, we will decrement a counter for any character that we see. If the count of a search character hits the 0, then we will decrement the “Match” counter. And, if that is 0, we found all search characters and the condition is fulfilled. We can then come to the calculation of the window positions.

Please note: We will only decrement the match counter, if, after decrementing the character counter, this will be 0.

Example (I will omit the noise with the ‘x’es):

- Search string “ABC”, source string: “xxAxxxxBBBxCAxx”.
- Initial character counters will be 1,1,1, the match counter will be 3.
- Reading the first ‘A’. Counters: 0,1,1  2
- Reading the first ‘B’. Counters: 0,0,1  1
- Reading the 2nd ‘B’. Counters: 0,-1,1  1 (We will decrement the match counter only if character counter hits the 0).
- Reading the 3rd ‘B’. Counters: 0,-2,1  1 (We will decrement the match counter only if character counter hits the 0).
- Reading the first ‘C’. Counters: 0,-2,0  0. The match counter is 0, the condition is fulfilled.

Please note. Negative character counts indicate that there are more of the same character further right.

Next, since the condition is fulfilled now, we will check the positions of the sliding window. The end position is clear. This is the last read character from the source string. This led to the fulfillment of the condition. So, easy.

To get the start position of the sliding window, we will check from the beginning of the source string, where we can find a search character. We will increment its count, and if the count is greater then 0, we will again increment the match count. If the match count is greater than 0, we found a start position. Counters now: 1,-2,0  1

The start position will be incremented for the next check. We will never start again with 0, but only with the last used start position.

OK, having found a start and end position, we have our first window and will look for potential smaller windows. We will continue to read the source string and check

- After the calculation of the sliding window position, the counter will be: 1,-2,0  1
- Reading the next ‘A’. Counters: 0,-2,0  0. Again, the condition is fulfilled.
- We continue with sliding window detection. The last start position was pointing to the character ‘x’ after the first ‘A’
- Increment start position and skip all ‘x’es. Continue
- Reading the first ‘B’. Counters: 0,-1,0  0
- Reading the 2nd ‘B’. Counters: 0,0,0  0
- Reading the 3d ‘B’. Counters: 0,1,0  1. Window position calculation done. Start position is the 3rd B. This window is smaller than the previous one, so take it.

Since the source string is consumed, we are done and found the solution.

How to implement that. We will do a small abstraction of the counter and pack it into a mini class. That will encapsulate the inner handling of character and match counts and can be optimized later.

A counter, which works for all kind of char types could be implemented like the below:

```
struct SpecialCounterForGeneralChar {

    std::unordered_map<char, int> individualLetter{};
    int necessaryMatches{};

    SpecialCounterForGeneralChar(const std::string& searchLetters) {
        for (const char c : searchLetters) individualLetter[c]++;
        necessaryMatches = individualLetter.size();
    }
    inline void incrementFor(const char c) {
        individualLetter[c]++;
        if (individualLetter[c] > 0)
            ++necessaryMatches;
    }
    inline void decrementFor(const char c) {
        individualLetter[c]--;
        if (individualLetter[c] == 0)
            --necessaryMatches;
    }
    inline bool allLettersMatched() { return necessaryMatches == 0; }
};
```

If we know more about the input data and it is for example restricted to an 8 bit char, we can also use:

```
struct SpecialCounter {

    char individualLetter[256]{};
    int necessaryMatches{};

    SpecialCounter(const std::string& searchLetters) {
        for (const char c : searchLetters) {
            if (individualLetter[c] == 0) ++necessaryMatches;
            individualLetter[c]++;
        }
    }
    inline void incrementFor(const char c) {
        individualLetter[c]++;
        if (individualLetter[c] > 0)
            ++necessaryMatches;
    }
    inline void decrementFor(const char c) {
        individualLetter[c]--;
        if (individualLetter[c] == 0)
            --necessaryMatches;
    }
    inline bool allLettersMatched() { return necessaryMatches == 0; }
};
```

This will be slightly faster than the above (under the given restrictions)

And, then the rest of the program will then be just 15 lines of code.

The important message here is that we need to think very verylong, before we start to implement the first line of code.

A good selected algorithm and design, will help us to find an optimum solution.

Please see the complete example solution below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <limits>

using Index = unsigned int;

// We want to hide the implementation of the special counter to the outside world
struct SpecialCounter {

    char individualLetter[256]{};
    int necessaryMatches{};

    SpecialCounter(const std::string& searchLetters) {
        for (const char c : searchLetters) {
            if (individualLetter[c] == 0) ++necessaryMatches;
            individualLetter[c]++;
        }
    }
    inline void incrementFor(const char c) {
        individualLetter[c]++;
        if (individualLetter[c] > 0)
            ++necessaryMatches;
    }
    inline void decrementFor(const char c) {
        individualLetter[c]--;
        if (individualLetter[c] == 0)
            --necessaryMatches;
    }
    inline bool allLettersMatched() { return necessaryMatches == 0; }
};


std::string solution(std::string toBeSearchedIn, std::string toBeSearchedFor) {

    // Counter with somespecial properties
    SpecialCounter counter(toBeSearchedFor);

    // This will be slided. End of window is always last read character. Start of window may increase 
    Index currentWindowStart {};

    // The potential solution
    Index resultingWindowStart {};
    Index resultingWindowWith{ std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() };

    // Iterate over all characters of the string under evaluation
    for (Index index{}; index < toBeSearchedIn.length(); ++index) {

        // We saw a character. So, subtract from characters to be searched
        counter.decrementFor(toBeSearchedIn[index]);

        // If we hit and found all necessary characters and adjusted the sliding windows start position
        while (counter.allLettersMatched()) {

            // Calculate start and width of sliding window. So, if we found a new, more narrow window
            const unsigned int currentWindowWith{ index - currentWindowStart + 1 };
            if (currentWindowWith < resultingWindowWith) {

                // Remember one potential solution
                resultingWindowWith = currentWindowWith;
                resultingWindowStart = currentWindowStart;
            }

            // Now, for the sliding window. We saw and decremented thsi character before
            // Now we see it in the sliding window and increment it again.
            counter.incrementFor(toBeSearchedIn[currentWindowStart]);

            // Slide start of window to one to the right
            currentWindowStart++;
        }
    }
    return (resultingWindowWith != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()) ? toBeSearchedIn.substr(resultingWindowStart, resultingWindowWith) : "No solution";
}

int main()
{
    const std::string toBeSearchedIn{ "KKKADOBECODEBBBAANCKKK" };
    const std::string toBeSearchedFor = { "AABBC" };

    std::cout << "Solution:\n" << solution(toBeSearchedIn, toBeSearchedFor) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is part of an attempt at an exercise, this answer will not present a complete solution to the exercise problem that inspired it. Instead, it will do just what is asked: it will point out the main issue with the posted code, and how it can be discovered.

#### Code Examination

An artful approach is to check for mismatches between the requirements, design, and implementation; artful because this approach is more an art than a science, and you can easily lead yourself astray. This basically involves running through design and through implementation in your head, as if you were the processor, though perhaps examining only small parts of the code at a time.

Some of the implementation looks fine, such as: `end` advancing along in the outer loop, checking for a smaller window (and replacing the previous smallest window). Some could stand closer examination, such as removing entries from the window histogram after checking that the window is valid (for algorithm correctness, it's very useful to think of good loop invariants, such as 'the window should always be valid', and ensure they always hold true).

However, when you look at `check_map`, there's a mismatch. One problem requirement is:

> every character in `t` (*including duplicates*) is included in the window

While there is a slight ambiguity in the phrasing (if a character from `t` occurs in a window *more* than in `t`, is the window valid?), the straight reading of this requirement is that the count of a character in `s` must be at least the count of a character in `t`. In `check_map`, the counts are being compared exactly. This strongly suggests a place to examine more closely.

#### Testing

A semi-automated, systematic approach that can catch all sorts of bugs is using tests, both unit and integration (a search of this site and the web at large will explain these terms). One key part of tests is identifying edge cases to test. For example, if you try with the search string "ACBA" and pattern "AB", the example program correctly finds the minimum window "BA". However, for the search string "ACBBA", it returns "ACB" as the minimum window. This suggests the implementation has an issue with character counts, which makes `check_map` the prime suspect (and the lines that update `strr` the secondary suspect).

For another test, consider search string "A123B12345A12BA123A" and pattern "AAB". This has 3 potential windows, with the shortest in the middle. If you fix `check_map` and test your code against this test case, the code returns "A12BA123A", rather than "A12BA". This suggests something is either wrong with testing the window validity (`check_map` again) or with setting the answer. Some scaffolding code (e.g. printing `start`, `end` and `ans` when it's updated) will reveal the cause.

#### Debugging

The most general approach that can reveal an issue with implementation correctness is to use an interactive debugger. For the sample code, breakpoints can be set at various key points, such as beginning of loops and branches. You can furthermore make these breakpoints conditional, at the indices when the code should be finding new windows. If you do this, you'll find that `check_map` returns `false` in instances when you'd expect it to be returning `true`. From there, you can start stepping in to `check_map` to observe why it's doing this.

Once that's fixed, there is still an issue with the code, though you'll need a test case such as the one with "A123B12345A12BA123A" above, as the issue isn't apparent with the "ADOBECODEBANC" test case. Stepping through the inner loop and examining the various variables will reveal what's going wrong.

#### Check the API

Bugs basically all have one cause: you expect the code to do one thing, but it does something different. One source of this is misunderstanding an API, so it can be helpful to read the API documentation to make sure your understanding is correct. Typically, before going to the API you'll want to find the specific API calls that aren't behaving as you understand them, which debugging can reveal. I mention this because there is an API call in the sample code that is incorrect.

### Conclusion

Each of the above approaches leads to the same bug: the comparison in `check_map`. Two of them also can lead to an additional bug, given a suitable test case.

### Additional Notes

#### Efficiency

`Substring` examines & tracks not only those characters in `t`, but all characters. This leads to the inner loop body being executed (including updating `ans`) for every character in `s`, not only those that are present in the pattern. Generally, you should make an implementation correct, then make it efficient. However, in this case it's trivial to make `Substring` ignore characters that aren't in the pattern and is closer to the problem description.

#### Types

An earlier formulation of this answer, addressing an earlier formulation of the question, covered examining types to check that they're the most appropriate. For the updated question, this no longer leads to bug discovery.

One point from the early formulation still applies to designing a solution.

Conceptually, the most appropriate data type for the pattern characters and the characters in the current window would be a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). As the window shifts, characters can be added and removed simply from a multiset. The validity of the current window is a simple subset operation (`pattern ⊆ window`). However, `multiset` in the STL doesn't correspond to the mathematical multiset.